# today.strftime('%Y_%m_%d') - not returning current date

Tags: python

I have a perplexing problem.  I have a job that runs and creates an EXCEL file.  It appends the date on the end of the file as part of the name.  The problem is that the date that is getting appended is not TODAY, but TOMORROW's date.  the job is run at 2:00 am daily (CRON).  This was "handed" to me because the person who created the program was terminated as part of a company layoff.  I know some PYTHON, but I cannot seem to determine why this is happening.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.now()

#grab data and header names and format data into namedtuples

self._entryData = ReaderManager(config.config['path'] + 'data/processing/concur_entries_' + today.strftime('%Y_%m_%d') + '.xlsx').read()
self._Entry = namedtuple('Entry', map(lambda s: s[:1].lower() + s[1:], [re.sub(r'[^\w]', '', header) for header in self._entryData[0]]))
self._entryData = map(lambda x: self._Entry(*x), self._entryData[1:])
```

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: More importantly, what timezone is the server that runs the script using?

Comment: The code sample you've provided seems to only be reading from a file with the current date; the code that creates the file does not seem to be shown.

Comment: Thanks for the timezone suggestion.  I thought about that, but it "should not" make a difference.  I am in Illinois (CST) and the servers are in Ohio (EST).  That would account for a minor time shift, but not enough to make the program(s) think it is tomorrow - a 24 hour time shift.

Comment: Sorry if I grabbed the code from the wrong program (read and not write).  I'm still trying to pull all of the pieces together. In either case, the program(s) are using the same process "today.strftime('%Y_%m_%d')" to obtain the dates and append that to the write/read routines.,